# How do I put unicode characters in my Antlr grammar?

Tags: unicode, internationalization, antlr, parsing

I'm trying to build a grammar with the following:

NUMERIC: INTEGER | FLOAT | INFINITY | PI
...
INFINITY: '∞'
PI: 'π'

But Antlr refuses to load the grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Java expression representing the Unicode character:

- 'π' = '\u03C0'
- '∞' = '\u221E'

That will work up to '\uFFFF'; Java doesn't support five-digit Unicode.

Comment: Did you get the values backwards? I see `\u03C0` as π and `\u221E` as ∞.